# Adding Column Using Subsonic 3.0.0.5 Migration

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I want to know that How to Insert New Columns to an existing database Table using Subsonic 3.0.0.5 MIGRATIONS.

Basically I want to alter an existing table in MS SqlServer database and add three more columns into it.

Please tell me How I will be able to do it

Regards,

Naveed Khan

Answer (score 1):

Just change your object and the column will be added/updated whatever. So if you have an object called "Post" and add a property, it will be added as a column in the DB.

See this video...

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Simple_Repo_5_Minute_Demo

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the conventions of SubSonic.
As the object is singular, it adds the plural to the table (or expects the table to be plural).
So it will expect an object called Order to map to a table called Orders.

There is only two solutions that I can see for you

1) Rename you table to the plural name.

2) Modify Subsonic code to remove the adding of the plural.